# Are there any other ways to be able to change ability sets besides dying?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

As far as I know, the only way you can change ability sets when playing online is to die at the hands of another player or get stunned in a "team" game.  Unfortunately it's just not possible to commit suicide without getting assistance from your pursuer and it's inconvenient giving free points to a pursuer/target just because you want to change abilities.

Are there any other methods to be able to switch ability sets in the game that I'm not aware of?

<sub>On a side note, this question stems from this PC bug that prevents me from changing ability sets in team games between rounds.  I don't get the "round changing" screen, I'm just left wandering the map until everyone else spawns which makes playing team games for me very frustrating.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unfortunately no other ways than the two you mention to change the ability set during a session. It's indeed sometimes frustrating as you say (even more I can imagine if you experience a bug on top of it).
If you *have to die*, try heading for an honorable death, canceling your pursuer's bonuses.